# Best stats and professions for Paladins

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have a Paladin that I played when 'Wrath of the Lich King' was still the latest patch (3.5.5), but never played with him since. A lot has changed in terms of how they work and how to achieve maximum DPS.

My question is, considering these changes, is Strength still the best stat to stack (for Retribution PvE Paladin)? Regardless of that, which other stats are a good idea to stack?

Also, is Jewelcrafting and Enchanting a good choice for my Blood Elf Paladin?

Comment: Icy-Veins is one of the go-tos for answering this type of question. They some up the best professions for ret pally here: http://icy-veins.com/retribution-paladin-wow-pve-dps-gems-enchants-professions-consumables#sec-4 , and stat priority here: http://icy-veins.com/retribution-paladin-wow-pve-dps-statistics-priority-reforging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't played WoW since the end of Cataclysm, so take my answer with a grain of salt.

For the melee DPS (warrior pally and dk) strength has always been the gem to stack no matter what, *unless* you are missing a crucial stat, like being **uncapped** on Hit Rating. This stat should be increased to the necessary level (is it still 8%?) to be on par for DPS.

**GOOD PROFS**

1. Blacksmithing : Extra sockets for more Red gems. Socket Bracer & Socket Gloves
   +320 Strength
2. Tailoring : Only decent embroidery -> Swordguard Embroidery (-180 Critical Strike, Hit or -200 Stamina; +1,000 Attack Power)
3. Leather working : Fur Lining - Strength (+320 Strength)
4. Jewel Crafting : Jeweler's Facet x2 +320 Strength
5. Herbalism: +480 Haste
6. Engineering : Synapse Springs (+320 Strength)
7. Enchanting : Enchant Ring - Greater Strength (+320 Strength)
8. Inscription : Secret Tiger Fang Inscription (+320 Strength)
9. Alchemy : Alchemist's Flask (+320 Strength

**Don't Bother**

1. Skinning: Master of Anatomy (+480 Critical Strike) /*leave it to the rogues*/
2. Mining: Toughness (+480 Stamina) /*leave it to the tanks*/

**My Concensus**: (based on your gains, plus money-generation potential and helping out guilds)

1. Jewel crafting: **EVERYONE USES GEMS.** Period. Money to be make, all guildies benefit, and not having to buy your own gems is a huge plus (this helped gear my 2nd 85 draenei pally way faster).
2. Blacksmithing: Extra gem slots, and you make the appropriate type of armor for yourself. Tied with JC.
3. Enchanting: Everyone needs enchants and pots for maximizing DPS. Free enchants are sweet too! Tied w/ Alchemy because $money$ and guildie help, but not as focused towards your character. (you are a BElf, so maybe consider it...)
4. Alchemy: Everyone needs pots and enchans for maximizing DPS. Tied w/ Enchanting because $money$ and guildie help, but not as focused towards your character.
5. Herbalism: Gives haste which isn't optimal, but the herbs can be worth **A LOT** and help guildies for flasks and glyphs.
6. Inscription: One stat boost, and glyphs are easy/cheap to buy in most scenarios. This does help all guildies though, unlike tailoring.
7. Tailoring: one mod on an item and a cool mount. However your items will only benefit clothies.
8. Engineering: Although the gizmos and gadgets are cool (plus a mount), I feel like there is more utility for Engineering in PVP than in PVE.
9. Leatherworking: 1 stat boost, you don't use leather armor. **NOT WORTH**

**Conclusion**

I'd pick any of the top 4, but as a Belf maybe you'll lean towards Enchanting. If you want to be self-oriented, go BS + JC or BS + Ench. Helping others would be Alchemy and Enchanting. Finally, making money should be JC + Ench.

*Sorry if the last part is a bit off topic, but I could finally write an answer to something I knew really well, so I thought I should give you all the options*

**tl,dr;**

A BElf RET PVE Pally should go BS + JC to optimize his efforts in gearing/performing better in raids.

Comment: Overall a good list of information for a paladin in the Cataclysm expansion, but the info is a bit outdated for the Mists of Pandaria expansion.

Comment: Yea, I'm sorry :( haven't touched the Panda-pack. Out of curiosity, (and because I'm thinking of getting back into the game), what has changed in MoP that would make something else more advantageous than what I have listed here?

Comment: Oh don't get me wrong, most of the information I saw that was outdated was mainly the stat gains for the different profession bonuses.(example- 320 strength enchant for blacksmithing would be something along the lines of 640 strength[I can't remember exactly what the numbers were, but they would obviously have increased with the newest expansion])